# Openerp V7 : Invoke or Call javascript function in Xml file

Tags: javascript, odoo

I need some basic help in OpenERP. I'm trying to call a javascript code in XML file but it doesnt fires the action.

My Action Code:

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function drawTree() {
              var data = [          
                {
                 "firstname": "S",
                  "lastname": "Brown",
                  "age": 16,
                }];      
              var options = {
                'width': '400px',
                'height': '200px'
                };       
            var container = document.getElementById('mytree');
            var tree = new links.TreeGrid(container, options);      
            tree.draw(data);
            }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="drawTree();">
      <div id="mytree"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Can Anyone help me how to refine my code as suit for OpenERP?